Category where objects form a set but not morphisms
I recently found out that a category $\mathscr{C}$ is small if it is locally small and $\mathrm{Obj}(\mathscr{C})$ forms a set. I tried to think of a category that is not locally small but $\mathrm{Obj}(\mathscr{C})$ still forms a set.
I presume one can do a similar construction to $BG$ (where $\mathrm{Obj}(BG)=\{\clubsuit\}$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(\clubsuit,\clubsuit)$ is a given group $G$), having a singleton as $\mathrm{Obj}(\mathscr{C})$ and endowing it with some proper class $\mathscr{H}$ as homomorphisms. However, nothing came to my mind that could fit the role of $\mathscr{H}$ and have an operation. Plus, I have had no luck wording this question on a search engine in a satisfying manner.
Apologies if this was answered previously or I made a trivial question, and thank you for reading!

I entered "examples of categories that are not locally small" into site search and the 3rd result is the linked duplicate.

Please do not answer in the comments, @HagenvonEitzen.
